# Multiple source_ids in a "stream" FQL query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Since some time I'm getting inconsistent behavior when using multiple source_ids in an FQL query to the *stream* table. The query is e.g.:

```
SELECT source_id, post_id, created_time, message, permalink, type, attachment 
FROM stream 
WHERE (created_time >= 1338444667) and 
      ((source_id = 74133697733  and actor_id = 74133697733) or 
       (source_id = 259126564951 and actor_id = 259126564951))
```

It seems that the timespan from which posts are returned is quite limited. But what's the cutoff value? Sometimes I'm not getting posts from 30 minutes ago, sometimes I'm getting multiple posts from between 2 and 3 hours ago, only to stop getting all of them on the next query. Is there a rule?

There's no mention of special multi-source_id queries treatment in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/.